# Memory Game - How to match with different images?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I know it might sound strange but i need to make a memory game that matches different images instead of two same images, like for an example, number one and a hand with raised index finger

Here is my actual code that matches two same images, it clones the card making the same image appear twice

Scene Controller below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {

public const int gridRows = 2;
public const int gridCols = 5;
public const float offsetX = 4f;
public const float offsetY = 5f;

[SerializeField] private MainCard originalCard;
[SerializeField] private Sprite[] images;

private void Start()
{
    Vector3 startPos = originalCard.transform.position; //The first position of the cards, all other cards are based on this one

    int[] numbers = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};
    numbers = ShuffleArray(numbers); 

    for(int i = 0; i < gridCols; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < gridRows; j++)
        {
            MainCard card;
            if(i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                card = originalCard;
            }
            else
            {
                card = Instantiate(originalCard) as MainCard;
            }

            int index = j * gridCols + i;
            int id = numbers[index];
            card.ChangeSprite(id, images[id]);

            float posX = (offsetX * i) + startPos.x;
            float posY = (offsetY * j) + startPos.y;
            card.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, startPos.z);
        }
    }
}

private int[] ShuffleArray(int[] numbers)
{
    int[] newArray = numbers.Clone() as int[];
    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
    {
        int tmp = newArray[i];
        int r = Random.Range(i, newArray.Length);
        newArray[i] = newArray[r];
        newArray[r] = tmp;
    }
    return newArray;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private MainCard _firstRevealed;
private MainCard _secondRevealed;

private int _match = 5;
[SerializeField] private TextMesh matchLabel;

public bool canReveal
{
    get { return _secondRevealed == null; }
}

public void CardRevealed(MainCard card)
{
    if(_firstRevealed == null)
    {
        _firstRevealed = card;
    }
    else
    {
        _secondRevealed = card;
        StartCoroutine(CheckMatch());
    }
}

private IEnumerator CheckMatch()
{
    if(_firstRevealed.id == _secondRevealed.id)
    {
        _match--;
        matchLabel.text = "Pares Restantes: " + _match;
        if(_match == 1){
            matchLabel.text = "Somente " + _match + " Par Restante";
        }
        if(_match == 0){
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        _firstRevealed.Unreveal();
        _secondRevealed.Unreveal();
    }

    _firstRevealed = null;
    _secondRevealed = null;

}

public void Menu()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
}

public void Fases()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
}

public void Sair()
{
    Application.Quit ();
}

public void Level1()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 1");
}

public void Sucesso()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
}

}
```

Main Card Class Below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCard : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private SceneController controller;
[SerializeField] private GameObject Card_Back;


public void OnMouseDown()
{
    if(Card_Back.activeSelf && controller.canReveal)
    {
        Card_Back.SetActive(false);
        controller.CardRevealed(this);
    }
}


private int _id;
public int id
{
    get { return _id; }
}

public void ChangeSprite(int id, Sprite image)
{
    _id = id;
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = image; //Isso pega o Sprite Renderer e muda a propriedade do Sprite
}

public void Unreveal()
{
    Card_Back.SetActive(true);
}
```

}

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: You told us what you want to do (your project intentions), but not the actual problem. which snippet of code is not working, why isnt it working, what results do you expect, what results is it giving you, what have you tried?

Comment: Well i just want to know how to do it, i don't have an actual problem, everything is working there, but instead of making matches with the same cards (which is what my code is doing) i want to match with different cards, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Each card is a prefab with a Card script. That script has a value (bit, string,enum....) when two cards are flipped, compare the values on each card. If same you got a match regardless of what they display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate each image in an object of a class like this simple example:

```
class CardImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite cardSprite;
    public int cardNumber;
}
```

Then in your game logic, you can check the cardNumber field for comparing two cards like this :

```
if (card1.cardNumber == card2.cardNumber)
{
// Do what you have to do when two cards are equal
}
```

For more information about OOP and Encapsulation see [this](https://medium.com/@zachcaceres/notes-for-noobs-object-oriented-basics-for-unity3d-d98685235ebb)

Comment: Ok, but my code instead of having each card a sprite, it does clone the first and only card with me just selecting the sprites with unity and it checks if the sprites are equal, so i don't think i can have card1 and card2, and a question, the cardNumber would be the id?
I added my MainCard class in my question by the way.
Here is a picture of how i put the sprites in unity [link](https://imgur.com/7r9Nr07)

Comment: @Lucwar Yes, it could be the id, you can check cards by their id instead of their sprites. The important note is that the cards who are the same must have equal id's.